# Parameterized tests fail with mvn test

Tags: java, maven, junit, lombok, parameterized

I'm struggeling quite a bit with a simple parameterized java test and couldn't find a proper solution :-S

Maybe you can give a hint where i missed something.

Following scenarios I have been testing
running with

- intellij -> no error, all tests pass
- `mvn clean -Dtest:KnockoutTests test` -> no error, all tests pass
- `mvn clean test` (locally and on jenkins) -> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

[image: failing set initialisation]

When I'm copying the exactly generated `hashCode` method in my class `RoundDefinition` it works just fine. But I don't want to explicitely override the `hashCode` method with exactly the generated one... (and this cannot be the solution obviously)

Models

```java
@Entity
@Data
@Table( name = "tbl_rounddefinition" )
@JsonIgnoreProperties( value = { "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler", }, ignoreUnknown = true )
@ToString( exclude = { "tournament" } )
@EqualsAndHashCode( exclude = { "tournament" } )
public class RoundDefinition implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = IDENTITY )
    @Column( name = "rounddefinition_id" )
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    @JoinColumn( name = "rounddefinition_linktournamentid" )
    @JsonIdentityInfo( generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id" )
    @JsonIdentityReference( alwaysAsId = true )
    private Tournament tournament;

    @Column( name = "rounddefinition_round" )
    private Integer round;

    @Column( name = "rounddefinition_numberOfRoundresults" )
    private Integer numberOfRoundresults;
}
```

```java
@Data
@ToString( exclude = { [...] } )
@EqualsAndHashCode( exclude = { [...], "roundDefinitions" } )
@Entity
@Table( name = "tbl_tournament" )
@JsonIgnoreProperties( value = { "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" }, ignoreUnknown = true )
public class Tournament implements Serializable {

[...]

    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "tournament", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true )
    @JsonSerialize( using = CollectionSerializer.class )
    @JsonDeserialize( using = CollectionDeserializer.class )
    @OrderBy( " round ASC " )
    private Set<RoundDefinition> roundDefinitions = new HashSet<>();

[...]

}
```

Test

```java
@RunWith( Parameterized.class )
@Slf4j
public class KnockoutTests {

    @InjectMocks
    private Knockout underTest;

    @Mock
    private MatchRepository matchRepository;

    private Integer tournamentSize;
    private Integer expectedMatchSize;
    private Integer expectedMaxRound;
    private List<RoundDefinition> roundDefinitions;

    public KnockoutTests( Integer tournamentSize, Integer expectedMatchSize, Integer expectedMaxRound,
            List<RoundDefinition> roundDefinitions )
    {
        this.tournamentSize = tournamentSize;
        this.expectedMatchSize = expectedMatchSize;
        this.expectedMaxRound = expectedMaxRound;
        this.roundDefinitions = roundDefinitions;
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks( this );
    }

    @Test
    public void testGenerate() {
        Tournament tournament = new Tournament();
        tournament.setTeamsize( 1 );
        System.out.println( "############# " + roundDefinitions.toString() + " #############" );
        tournament.setRoundDefinitions( new HashSet<>( roundDefinitions ) ); // <<-- Here I'm getting this weird ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions
        [...]
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters( name = "{index}: Test with tournamentSize={0}, expectedMatchSize: {1}, expectedMaxRound: {2}" )
    public static Collection testData() {
        return Arrays.asList( new Object[][] {
                { 1, 1, 1, new ArrayList<RoundDefinition>() {{
                    add( getRoundDefinition( 1L, 1, 1 ) );
                }} },
                { 2, 1, 1, new ArrayList<RoundDefinition>() {{
                    add( getRoundDefinition( 1L, 1, 1 ) );
                }} },
                { 15, 15, 4, new ArrayList<RoundDefinition>() {{
                    add( getRoundDefinition( 1L, 1, 1 ) );
                    add( getRoundDefinition( 2L, 3, 3 ) );
                    add( getRoundDefinition( 3L, 4, 5 ) );
                }} },
                { 16, 15, 4, new ArrayList<RoundDefinition>() {{
                    add( getRoundDefinition( 1L, 1, 1 ) );
                }} },
                { 17, 31, 5, new ArrayList<RoundDefinition>() {{
                    add( getRoundDefinition( 1L, 1, 1 ) );
                }} },
                { 129, 255, 8, new ArrayList<RoundDefinition>() {{
                    add( getRoundDefinition( 1L, 1, 1 ) );
                }} },
                { 256, 255, 8, new ArrayList<RoundDefinition>() {{
                    add( getRoundDefinition( 1L, 1, 1 ) );
                }} },
                { 257, 511, 9, new ArrayList<RoundDefinition>() {{
                    add( getRoundDefinition( 1L, 1, 1 ) );
                    add( getRoundDefinition( 2L, 3, 3 ) );
                    add( getRoundDefinition( 3L, 4, 5 ) );
                }} }
        } );
    }

    private static RoundDefinition getRoundDefinition( long id, int round, int numberOfRoundresults ) {
        RoundDefinition rd = new RoundDefinition();
        rd.setId( id );
        rd.setRound( round );
        rd.setNumberOfRoundresults( numberOfRoundresults );
        return rd;
    }
[...]
}
```

Console output

```
############# [RoundDefinition(id=1, tournament=null, round=1, numberOfRoundresults=1)] #############

############# [RoundDefinition(id=1, tournament=null, round=1, numberOfRoundresults=1), RoundDefinition(id=2, tournament=null, round=3, numberOfRoundresults=3), RoundDefinition(id=3, tournament=null, round=4, numberOfRoundresults=5)] #############
############# [RoundDefinition(id=1, tournament=null, round=1, numberOfRoundresults=1)] #############
############# [RoundDefinition(id=1, tournament=null, round=1, numberOfRoundresults=1)] #############
############# [RoundDefinition(id=1, tournament=null, round=1, numberOfRoundresults=1)] #############
############# [RoundDefinition(id=1, tournament=null, round=1, numberOfRoundresults=1)] #############
############# [RoundDefinition(id=1, tournament=null, round=1, numberOfRoundresults=1), RoundDefinition(id=2, tournament=null, round=3, numberOfRoundresults=3), RoundDefinition(id=3, tournament=null, round=4, numberOfRoundresults=5)] #############
Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 8, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.015 sec <<< FAILURE! - in pkg.service.tournament.handler.generator.KnockoutTests
testGenerate[0: Test with tournamentSize=1, expectedMatchSize: 1, expectedMaxRound: 1](pkg.service.tournament.handler.generator.KnockoutTests)  Time elapsed: 0.008 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 35
    at pkg.model.entities.RoundDefinition.hashCode(RoundDefinition.java:26)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
    at java.util.HashSet.<init>(HashSet.java:120)
    at pkg.service.tournament.handler.generator.KnockoutTests.testGenerate(KnockoutTests.java:67)

testGenerate[1: Test with tournamentSize=2, expectedMatchSize: 1, expectedMaxRound: 1](pkg.service.tournament.handler.generator.KnockoutTests)  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 35
    at pkg.model.entities.RoundDefinition.hashCode(RoundDefinition.java:26)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:339)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
    at java.util.HashSet.<init>(HashSet.java:120)
    at pkg.service.tournament.handler.generator.KnockoutTests.testGenerate(KnockoutTests.java:67)
```

Generated code by lombok

```java
public int hashCode() {
        int PRIME = true;
        int result = 1;
        Object $id = this.getId();
        int result = result * 59 + ($id == null ? 43 : $id.hashCode());
        Object $round = this.getRound();
        result = result * 59 + ($round == null ? 43 : $round.hashCode());
        Object $numberOfRoundresults = this.getNumberOfRoundresults();
        result = result * 59 + ($numberOfRoundresults == null ? 43 : $numberOfRoundresults.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
```

## #2 Edit:

switched to an explicit generation

```java
Set<RoundDefinition> definitions = new HashSet<>(  );
        for (RoundDefinition rd : roundDefinitions) {
            RoundDefinition asd = new RoundDefinition();
            asd.setRound( rd.getRound() );
            asd.setNumberOfRoundresults( rd.getNumberOfRoundresults() );
            definitions.add(asd); // <-- ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        }
```

## #3 Edit:

Out of curiosity i tried to add an element to a different set of class

```java
Set<Tournament> tournamentSet = new HashSet<>();
tournamentSet.add(new Tournament()); <-- ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Also add such initialisation to an other test... same behaviour o.O
BUT i can add string to a `HashSet<String>`... the heck is going on here :-D

## #4 Edit:

checked dependencies for change but they seem to be same with source branch. Also reproducable in source branch...

## #5 Edit:

Removed the lombok annotation "@Data" from my model "RoundDefinition", wrote getter and setter myself and the tests work again just fine...
using lombok v1.18.8

So why is it failing when lombok generates the hashCode and equals function....

Comment: Are you able to see the generated code for ```hashCode``` by Lombok to understand why would it throw a ArrayOutOfBoundException?

Comment: edited my question

Comment: I think there's something else going on here, the description as it is doesn't make sense. I'd suggest making an [mcve] and working out which specific part of the puzzle is causing the problem. Maybe start by taking out the complexity of the parameterised test - just write a single unit test.

Comment: Yup that's gonna be my next try. FYI I just switched the `new HashSet<>( roundDefinitions )` to an explicit loop. I think there's something wrong with my entity class

Comment: Single test without any special runner fails when run with `mvn clean test` but finishes successfully when run `mvn clean -Dtest:KnockoutTests test` or with IDE. So exactly the same behaviour... wtf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soooo finally I've got to a point with which I can get on...

As I tested several tries, I noticed that my tests somehow worked again.

When I run the tests with profile they failed, when run without a profile they worked.
After some digging and refactoring I've got to the pom file of the project...

The plugin "maven-sufefire-plugin" was added 2 times like so

```xml
<project>
<profiles>
[...]
<profile>
 <id>unit-test</id>
  <plugins>
   [...]
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <argLine>
      ${argLine} -Dfile.encodeing=utf-8 -Duser.timezone=UTC
     </argLine>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
[...]
```

```xml
<project>
 <build>
  <plugins>
   [...]
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <argLine>
      -Dfile.encodeing=utf-8 -Duser.timezone=UTC
     </argLine>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
[...]
```

but the property `${argLine}` was not set in the pom file at all.
So I introduced a new property `<argLine>` and put those parameters in there.... and voilà it worked....
Don't know exactly why there is then an exception thrown in the hashcode method but maybe this helps someone else too :-)